# How to config unity to use setter injection only in my customeactionfilterattributes?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unity-container, structuremap

In structuremap its possible to config it so when using setter injection for actionfilterattribute it only injects and search for setter in customeactionfillterattribute like this :

```
SetAllProperties(x =>
            x.Matching(p =>
                p.DeclaringType.CanBeCastTo(typeof(ActionFilterAttribute)) &&
                p.DeclaringType.Namespace.StartsWith("myassemblyname") &&
                !p.PropertyType.IsPrimitive &&
                p.PropertyType != typeof(string)));
```

How to do it in unity?

is setting [Dependency] attribute enough?

Comment: IMO it's better do [not do dependency injection](http://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=98) in your attributes at all.

Comment: Nice article for large scale projects but it brings undesired complexity for small size projects.by using Simple Injector in "Dictionary<Type, Func<IWebApiFilter>> BuildActionFilters()" you have set the simple injector to search for related attributes what I would like to do with unity and couldn't find a way to do it.

Comment: Unity should have an API for querying the registered types, but I'm not sure how to do this.